# Is it natural to say "raise modern baby"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A friend and I were talking about the way **raise a modern baby** and I said

> The way **raise a modern baby** is much different to the way 30 years ago, we now have internet, social network, youtube, globalization which make sharing knowledge and information more efficient, accordingly the requirement for qualified employee has also changed ...

Is it natural to say "raise modern baby"?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, “raise” needs to be preceded by “to”.

While the phrase does make sense, it sounds perhaps a little odd, perhaps because the times are changing, but the babies we are trying to raise are not (i.e. they’re not “modern” per se); what's really changing is the "way", so it might make more sense to say:

> The modern way to raise a baby...

A very idiomatic way of saying this would be:

> The way to raise a baby in today’s world...

“Today’s world” is a common idiom that refers to the conditions we currently live in.

Comment: What's wrong with  "The modern way to raise a baby"?

Comment: @KateBunting Nothing at all - I've updated my answer to include a reference to this - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of [hypallage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage), which is mostly used in poetic or literary writing. I would avoid it in ordinary speech.